# VBA Excel send all info in only one email if one value is same

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, office-automation

I want send a email with VBA where I send user number to email address but if he have 2 user number he send the 2 user number in the same mail.

My code with my excel :[image: Excel]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim mail As Variant
    Dim ligne As Integer

    Set mail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'create an outlook object

    For ligne = 1 To 5

        If Range("n" & ligne) = "OK" Then

            With mail.CreateItem(olMailItem) ' informs the program that we want to send a mail.
                .Subject = TEST
                .To = Range("q" & ligne)
                .CC = "test@gmail.be"
                .Body = "Hi number " & Range("I" & ligne) & " You are owner of users :" 'users
                .SendUsingAccount = "test@gmail.com"
                .Display 'display the mail before sending it if not place send to send
            End With
            
        End If
        
    Next ligne
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for Edit TinMan I hope you can help me

Comment: What do you mean boy "if he have 2 user number he send the 2 user number in the same mail"? Where to "have" these "2 user numbers"? Is there in your picture such a situation? Should in column "I:I" be cases of cells containing two numbers? If so, how will they be separated? If not, please better describe what you want doing from the mentioned point of view.

Comment: Yes I mean if he have 2 user number he send the 2 user number in the same mail ?

Comment: Are there in the picture you show such "two numbers" and I missed them? I asked above, too: how are they separated (in the same cell)?

Comment: I would like to be able to send a single mail to test@gmail.com where I put in the mail the 2 user number instead of making 2 mail for test@gmail.com.

Comment: the frist is 42 and second 56

Comment: They are not in same cell

Comment: For exemple for test@gmail.com I have the same value but the user number change and I would like send this 2 info in one email and not 2

Comment: I would like to send only one email per person because in my excel the same email comes back several times

Comment: I hope I have explained myself well

Comment: If not, tell me

Comment: The column "I:I" is value

Comment: Like it is A B I J my screen is bad sorry

Comment: OK. And how do you like to write them in the mail body? Something like:  "Hi number " & Range("I" & ligne) & " and " & Range("I" & ligne +1) & "! You are owner of users :" 'users? What last 'users should mean?

Comment: You need a dictionary to extract unique mail accounts from "Q:Q" column (as keys) and numbers from "I:I" per each key. Then, iterate between the dictionary elements, extracting the required numbers. Now, is it possible to be more than 2 such occurrences? If so, how do you want them to be written in the body mail? In your code you should start iteration from the second row. Otherwise, your code takes the headers...

Comment: Yes I want something like this "Hi number " & Range("I" & ligne) & "! You are owner of users : " & Range("a" & ligne) & " and " & Range("a" & ligne +1) & "

Comment: Yes I will start iteration from second row

Comment: And yes it can be more than 2 username for one email

Comment: How can I do this ? " You need a dictionary to extract unique mail accounts from "Q:Q" column (as keys) and numbers from "I:I" per each key. Then, iterate between the dictionary elements, extracting the required numbers. "

Comment: It would be necessary that for each value that is linked to a mail I send a mail with all its username

Comment: Without send a 2 mails to the same person

Comment: OK. I will prepare a piece of code. Not right now, but soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, test the next updated code. It uses a dictionary to extract the unique mail accounts and all the necessary data to behave as you need. The code has a `Stop` line, after `.Display` to let you see how the new mail looks in its window. Do what is written in the respective line comment. Otherwise, it will create so  many new mail window as many UNIQUE records are in Q:Q:

```
Sub sendMailCond()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRQ As Long, arr, arrUs, i As Long
 Dim mail As Object, strUsers As String, dict As Object
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastRQ = sh.Range("Q" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on Q:Q
 arr = sh.Range("A2:Q" & lastRQ).Value 'place the range in an array for faster processing
 
 'Place the necessary data in the dictionary:
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the dictionary
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 14) Like "OK" Then
         If Not dict.exists(arr(i, 17)) Then
                dict.Add arr(i, 17), arr(i, 9) & "|" & arr(i, 1)
         Else
               dict(arr(i, 17)) = dict(arr(i, 17)) & "::" & arr(i, 1)
         End If
         
    End If
 Next i
 
 Set mail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'create an outlook object
 'extract the necessary data:
 For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
     arr = Split(dict.Items()(i), "|") 'split the item by "|" to extract value from I:I and a concatenation by "::" separator if more then one key exists
     arrUs = Split(arr(1), "::")

       If UBound(arrUs) > 0 Then
              strUsers = Join(arrUs, " / ")
       Else
              strUsers = arr(1)
       End If
      With mail.CreateItem(olMailItem) ' informs the program that we want to send a mail.
            .Subject = "Test"
            .To = dict.Keys()(i)
            .cc = "test@gmail.be"
            .body = "Hi number " & arr(0) & " You are owner of users : " & strUsers
            .SendUsingAccount = "test@gmail.com"
            .Display: Stop 'See the New mail in Outlook and check its contents
                           'press F5 to continue!
     End With
 Next i
End Sub
```

If it returns as you want, you can replace the line starting with `Disply` with `.Send`.

**Edited**:

The new version extracting from M:M, too and placing at the end of body:

```
Sub sendMailCond2()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRQ As Long, arr, arrUs, i As Long
 Dim mail As Object, strUsers As String, dict As Object
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 lastRQ = sh.Range("Q" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 arr = sh.Range("A2:Q" & lastRQ).Value
 
 'Place the necessary data in the dictionary:
 Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the dictionary
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 14) Like "OK" Then
         If Not dict.exists(arr(i, 17)) Then
                dict.Add arr(i, 17), arr(i, 9) & "|" & arr(i, 13) & "|" & arr(i, 1)
         Else
                dict(arr(i, 17)) = dict(arr(i, 17)) & "::" & arr(i, 1)
         End If
         
    End If
 Next i
 
 Set mail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'create an outlook object
 'extract the necessary data:
 For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
     arr = Split(dict.Items()(i), "|")
     arrUs = Split(arr(2), "::")

       If UBound(arrUs) > 0 Then
              strUsers = Join(arrUs, " / ") & ". Your last connection was " & arr(1)
       Else
              strUsers = arr(2) & ". Your last connection was " & arr(1)
       End If
      With mail.CreateItem(olMailItem) ' informs the program that we want to send a mail.
            .Subject = "Test"
            .To = dict.Keys()(i)
            .cc = "test@gmail.be"
            .body = "Hi number " & arr(0) & " You are owner of users : " & strUsers
            .SendUsingAccount = "test@gmail.com"
            .Display: Stop 'See the New mail in Outlook and check its contents
                           'press F5 to continue!
     End With
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248745/discussion-on-answer-by-faneduru-vba-excel-send-all-info-in-only-one-email-if-on).

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to make summarized table and then send from that table. In this code it adds new sheet, makes summarized table in it and sends from that table

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim mail As Variant, Owner As Variant, user As Variant
 Dim ligne As Integer, x As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, RowNum As Integer
 Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
 Dim found As Boolean
 
 Set ws = ActiveSheet
 Set ws2 = Sheets.Add
 ws2.Cells(1, "A") = "Value"
 ws2.Cells(1, "B") = "email"
 ws2.Cells(1, "C") = "Usernames"
 
 x = ws.Cells(1, "I").End(xlDown).Row 'get last row with data
 If x > 1 Then
     For i = 2 To x
      If ws.Range("n" & i) = "OK" Then
       Owner = ws.Cells(i, "I").Value
       user = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
       mail = ws.Cells(i, "Q").Value
       RowNum = ws2.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row with summarized data, asuming that there will not be more than 65536 owners
       If RowNum = 1 Then
         ws2.Cells(2, 1) = Owner
         ws2.Cells(2, 2) = mail
         ws2.Cells(2, 3) = user
       Else
        found = False
        For j = 2 To RowNum 'check if there already is such owner
         If ws2.Cells(j, 1) = Owner Then
          found = True
          ws2.Cells(j, 3) = ws2.Cells(j, 3).Value & ", " & user 'adds new Username to existing, delimiting by comma and space
          Exit For
         End If
        Next j
        If found = False Then
         ws2.Cells(RowNum + 1, 1) = Owner
         ws2.Cells(RowNum + 1, 2) = mail
         ws2.Cells(RowNum + 1, 3) = user
        End If
       End If 'Rownum>1
      End If '=OK
     Next i
     RowNum = ws2.Cells(65536, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
     If RowNum > 1 Then ' if there is at least 1 OK user

 Set mail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'create an outlook object

 For ligne = 2 To RowNum

     With mail.CreateItem(olMailItem) ' informs the program that we want to send a mail.
             .Subject = test
             .To = ws2.Range("b" & ligne)
             .CC = "test@gmail.be"
             .Body = "Hi number " & ws2.Range("A" & ligne) & " You are owner of users :" & ws2.Range("C" & ligne) 'users
             .SendUsingAccount = "test@gmail.com"
             .Display 'display the mail before sending it if not place send to send
         End With 
        End If
       Next ligne
      End If 'Rownum >1
     End If 'x>1
    End Sub
```